# Alternate between classes added jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, toggle, addclass

I have a 3 div's, the jQuery script adds a class when a div is clicked:

```
.red{ background-color: red; }
```

What I would like to do is to modify the jQuery so that once time the .`red` class is added an the next time it will add `.blue`, `.red`, `.blue` and so on...

My script ans you can [the in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/xAEjN/4/) is this:

```
var $a = $('.box');
$a.click(function(){

        $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

I'm sorry I'm not sharing more, but my horrid attempts wil just confuse.

I hope I have made myself clear, if not please ask!!

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE:**

**I think the question was not clear enough so I'll try to explain further.**

What a need bascially would be three div, the first click, turns the clicked div into **red**, the second turns the clicked into **blue**, and the red an so on, they should toggle (go turn red or blue when clicked agin the first click is the only one that counts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on the comments below, it sounds like you want the color to alternate for each subsequent item that is clicked, and it can not be revered.

This should do it:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/zUdWq/

```
$('a').click((function() {
    var i = 0;
    var colors = ['blue','red'];
    return function() {
        $(this).addClass( colors[i = ++i % 2] ).unbind('click');
    };
})());
```

This uses a closure to wrap around the variables. If you don't want/need that, here's the same thing without the closure.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/zUdWq/1/

```
var i = 0;
var colors = ['blue','red'];

$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass( colors[i = ++i % 2] ).unbind('click');
});
```

---

**Original answer:**

```
$a.addClass('red').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
});
```

This will start by adding the `red` class when the page loads, then will thereafter toggle `red` and `blue` upon each click.

If you wanted to start without any class on the item, then you could do this:

```
$a.click(function(){
    if( !this.className ) {
        this.className = 'red';
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
    }
});
```

Comment: That is brilliant!! thank you!! it is not exactly what I asked (because I described it incorrectly!) I will try to modify it, and maybe ask later :)

Comment: @patrick the thing is I don't want the to turn toggle, my prblem is that they shouldt be able to go back to the previous one, the one you select stays (like it was before) but now red blue red blue. I don't know if I have explained myself

Comment: @Akinator: I see. But how are they choosing between red or blue? Or do you mean for the first item they click, it is red, then the next item is blue, and so on?

Comment: @patrick no you are not choosing the first you choose turns red the second turns blue and they cant be changed back, is that clearer? thank you very much, sorry for a bad description in the begining!

Comment: @Akinator: I think I understand now. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: +1 and obviously accepted answer! this is EXACTLY what I needed!!! I'm sorry for not being of much help in the process and for a bad description of the problem in the beginning!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @patrcik Taylor made, literally ;)